# How can I have two "no matter what" in one preg_match script?

Tags: regex, preg-match

what can I do, when I have

```
if(preg_match('#<tr>(.*?)<td align="center" width="90%" valign="top">(.*?)<td align="center" width="90%" valign="top">#s',$result,$array)) { ... }
```

and I want to have only the second `(.*?)` to be written into the $array. What do I have to replace the first `(.*?)` with, when I just want to tell preg_match that there can be no matter what between the `<tr>` and the `<td align="center" ...`

Thanks for your help!
phpheini

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have a non-capturing group with `(?:.*?)`

Comment: Perfect, thank you!
Do you also know how I can get a url from this one:
preg_match('#referer\.php\?url=(.*?)#s',$result,$array2)
I want him to check the whole data in $result to find the code "referer.php?url=http://www.example.com" and to give me http://www.example.com

Comment: The ? causes the * to be non-greedy, so it eats as few input chars as possible.. (.*) would eat the rest of the URL, or ([^&]*) would eat everything up the next ampersand, or end of URL.